# C code - Split random list name from txt file into groups of 5 with different club name and write into new file

Tags: c, file, random, struct, grouping

I have a list of 30 names from txt file. it also include nick name, club, and points. i want to randomly split the names into 6 groups of 5 per-group. i dont know how to code for split random list name from txt file into groups of 5 with different club name and write into new file. Im very new with c programming, please help me. can you guys show me how to make it done? or any related example that i can use to add in my codes?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define p printf
#define s scanf

FILE *tf;

struct listName
{
    char name[100];
    char nickname[50];
    char club[50];
    int point;
};

int main()
{
    struct listName ln[30];

    //open file to read
    tf = fopen("ListnamePlayer.txt","r");

    int i;
    //read data from file
    for(i=0;i<30;i++)
    {
        fscanf(tf,"%[^\n]\n",ln[i].name);
        fscanf(tf,"%[^\n]\n",ln[i].nickname);
        fscanf(tf,"%[^\n]\n",ln[i].club);
        fscanf(tf,"%i\n",&ln[i].point);
    }

    //print data from file
    p("\n\n");
    p("*****************************************************************************************\n");
    p("| No |                Name                           Nickname       Club      Points    |\n");
    p("*****************************************************************************************\n");
    int j=1;
    for(i=0;i<30;i++)
    {
            p("| %2i.| ",j++);
            p(" %-45s ",ln[i].name);
            p(" %-10s ",ln[i].nickname);
            p(" %-10s ",ln[i].club);
            p(" %-5i    |\n",ln[i].point);
            p("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    }
    fclose(tf);
    return 0;
}
```

but i want it with different club and write it into a new file which looks like this

```
AHMAD NAIM BIN RUKMAN
Naim
**Chelsea**
1000
ANITH IZYAN BT ABDUL RAHMAN
Yan
**Dortmund**
1000
IMRAN HARITH BIN NOOR HASSAN
Meran
**Juventus**
1000
NURUL KHALIL SUFFI BIN AZIZ
Sufi
**Arsenal**
1000
MUHAMMAD NAQIUDDIN BIN JAAFAR
Naqiu
**Bayern**
1000

AIMAN HADI BIN BAHAMAM
Adi
Chelsea
1000
FARRAH MASTURAH LUBIS BINTI MD YUSOF
Farah
Dortmund
1000
NOOR RABIAH BINTI JAMINGON
Rab
West Ham
1000
MOHAMAD FAZRUL NAZMI BIN MOHAMED ISA
Faz
Juventus
1000
ZULKARNAIN BIN GHAZALI
Kanai
Arsenal
1000

AIMAN SYAZANA BINTI MUHIDDIN
Man
Chelsea
1000
HANIES AZYLEEA BINTI MOHD AZMAN
Hani
Dortmund
1000
MOHD KAMAL BIN SUHAIMI
Kamal
Bayern
1000
NABILAH AIMAN BINTI AHMAD RADZI
Aiman
West Ham
1000
MOHAMAD SYAFIQ BIN MOHAMMAD ZAKI
Fiq
Juventus
1000

HUDA BINTI SEHABUDIN
Huda
Dortmund
1000
IZZATI BALQIS BINTI A RAZAK
Qis
Juventus
1000
SHARIFAH NURNADHIRAH BINTI SYED ABDUL HAMID
Irah
Arsenal
1000
NIK AHMAD ZAIM BIN NIK MUHD KHUZAIDIN
Zaim
West Ham
1000
MOHD SHAFIQ IZZUDDIN BIN MOHD YUSOFF
Izudin
Bayern
1000

AMIR HAFIZI BIN MAZLAN
Amir
Chelsea
1000
MUHAMAD AMIR BIN AHMAD SAJURI
Amir
Bayern
1000
SYED NAZIRUL HARITH BIN SYED AB RAHMAN HILMI
Syed
Arsenal
1000
MUHAMMAD RASULUL HAKIM BIN MAT DAUD
Rasul
West Ham
1000
MOHAMMAD ANAS AMIR BIN ALWI
Rima Sana
Juventus
1000


AMIRA SYAHMINA BINTI SUHAIMI
Mina
Chelsea
1000
AZFAR HAKIM BIN KAMARIZAN
Akim
Dortmund
1000
MUHAMAD NAZREEN FAZRIQ BIN AZLAN
Naz
Bayern
1000
NUR ASHRAF ISKANDAR BIN OSMAN
Ashraf
West Ham
1000
SITI FARHANA BINTI MAT MAZALI
Anna
Arsenal
1000
```

This is my text file

```
AHMAD NAIM BIN RUKMAN
Naim
Chelsea
1000
AIMAN HADI BIN BAHAMAM
Adi
Chelsea
1000
AIMAN SYAZANA BINTI MUHIDDIN
Man
Chelsea
1000
AMIR HAFIZI BIN MAZLAN
Amir
Chelsea
1000
AMIRA SYAHMINA BINTI SUHAIMI
Mina
Chelsea
1000
ANITH IZYAN BT ABDUL RAHMAN
Yan
Dortmund
1000
AZFAR HAKIM BIN KAMARIZAN
Akim
Dortmund
1000
FARRAH MASTURAH LUBIS BINTI MD YUSOF
Farah
Dortmund
1000
HANIES AZYLEEA BINTI MOHD AZMAN
Hani
Dortmund
1000
HUDA BINTI SEHABUDIN
Huda
Dortmund
1000
IMRAN HARITH BIN NOOR HASSAN
Meran
Juventus
1000
IZZATI BALQIS BINTI A RAZAK
Qis
Juventus
1000
MOHAMAD FAZRUL NAZMI BIN MOHAMED ISA
Faz
Juventus
1000
MOHAMAD SYAFIQ BIN MOHAMMAD ZAKI
Fiq
Juventus
1000
MOHAMMAD ANAS AMIR BIN ALWI
Rima Sana
Juventus
1000
MOHD KAMAL BIN SUHAIMI
Kamal
Bayern
1000
MOHD SHAFIQ IZZUDDIN BIN MOHD YUSOFF
Izudin
Bayern
1000
MUHAMAD AMIR BIN AHMAD SAJURI
Amir
Bayern
1000
MUHAMAD NAZREEN FAZRIQ BIN AZLAN
Naz
Bayern
1000
MUHAMMAD NAQIUDDIN BIN JAAFAR
Naqiu
Bayern
1000
MUHAMMAD RASULUL HAKIM BIN MAT DAUD
Rasul
West Ham
1000
NABILAH AIMAN BINTI AHMAD RADZI
Aiman
West Ham
1000
NIK AHMAD ZAIM BIN NIK MUHD KHUZAIDIN
Zaim
West Ham
1000
NOOR RABIAH BINTI JAMINGON
Rab
West Ham
1000
NUR ASHRAF ISKANDAR BIN OSMAN
Ashraf
West Ham
1000
NURUL KHALIL SUFFI BIN AZIZ
Sufi
Arsenal
1000
SHARIFAH NURNADHIRAH BINTI SYED ABDUL HAMID
Irah
Arsenal
1000
SITI FARHANA BINTI MAT MAZALI
Anna
Arsenal
1000
SYED NAZIRUL HARITH BIN SYED AB RAHMAN HILMI
Syed
Arsenal
1000
ZULKARNAIN BIN GHAZALI
Kanai
Arsenal
1000
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow. I've read your question and it is not clear what you are asking. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you would like to get help on this site.

Comment: Hi, i want to randomly split the name list from text file into group of 5 but i dont know how to write the code. Can you help me by showing some example or any related codes?

Comment: @sukilsun.:group of 5 means? 5 files contatining random entries?

Comment: @coderredoc: Im sorry if my question is not clear for you. but the thing is i want to make randomly split the list of 30 names from text file(ListnamePlayer.txt) into 6 group as 1 group have 5 person on it but people form the same club cannot be in the same group and write it into a new text file (GroupingPlayer.txt).

Comment: @sukilsun.: You can read one entry and then write it to a file. Which file to write will be dictated by a `rand()`...

Comment: Thanks @coderredoc, but how to do the grouping? and how to divide the people into group without having same club?

Comment: wait a sec...@sukilsun so you want in 6 files. Each file has 5 person. Each person in a file will have different club? Now am I right?

Comment: yes @coderredoc it can be that way and can you show me how? please. But if possible can it be only just in 1 file?

Comment: @sukilsun.: You want code? or the idea?

Comment: @coderredoc i want the code if its not a trouble for you, or just a simple code that might help me doing this program. help me please

Comment: @coderredoc help me please

Comment: @sukilsun.: Read each record in a structure and write it in file. The program boi;ls down to this. You can do it if you try.

Comment: @coderredoc can you give me some idea on how to randomly divide the group and having different club? which is to scan the file first, if it doesn't have matching values, then i will write the names(data) into the file. If it have match value, it skip the list till it find non -matching values.

Comment: Look, you have said that you will divide it randomly, so what you will do, read all the members - now classify each member in different arrays. As a result now yu have 6 club arrays. Now in each file, you need member of each club, you randomly select that and out it. @sukilsun